# Why can I run this locally and not over X?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, osx, qtcreator

I am trying to run qtcreator. It powers up fine on the local (Ubuntu 16.4) box, but when I try to run it over X to a Mac I get this:

```
(qtcreator:3893): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-LglOS2bxyZ: Connection refused
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

Searching these messages usually suggests that this is a driver problem and suggest a fix on the (local) box, but that doesn't seem relevant here. Any ideas as to how I might fix this so I can run it remotely?

(NB: the qtcreator process is still running when this happens, just 'headless' and useless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some sort of OpenGL issue, but I was able to get qtcreator to run by installing VirtualGL at both the client and server sides: http://www.virtualgl.org/Main/HomePage